# Can't set value of Text View to result of non static method in either activity or fragment class

Tags: java, android, android-fragments

I have an activity--Portfolio Activity--where I'm trying to set the value of a Text View to the result of a method--getPriceofCoins--that when called retrieves and returns a value from a sqlite database.  When the activity is created, the text view will be changed to reflect the value recorded in the database.

I'm currently working with these methods: this part works fine

```
      //In the activity class:

      public  double getPriceOfCoins(String coinType) {
            UserData userData = new UserData(getApplicationContext());
            SQLiteDatabase database = userData.getReadableDatabase();

            String rows_to_return[] = {"price_of_coin"};

            Cursor cursor = database.query("portfolio", rows_to_return, "type_of_coin = '" + coinType + "'", null, null, null, null);

            Log.d("woops", cursor.getColumnCount() + "");

            Log.d("woops", cursor.moveToFirst() + "");


            return cursor.getDouble(0);



        }
```

And in the inner fragment class:

```
  @Override
            public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                    Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_port_folio, container, false);
                TextView priceView = (TextView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.portfolio_value_of_bitcoin_label);

                priceView.setText(getPriceOfCoins("Bitcoin") + "");




                return rootView;
            }
```

This doesn't compile, because I can't refer to the non static getPriceOfCoins method from the static fragment inner class; on the other hand I can't put it in the Activity's OnCreate method because findViewById yields a null pointer exception during runtime.

Research on other topics here on stack overflow has demonstrated that the latter error occurs because the layout hasn't been inflated yet--this
 happens in the inner fragment class's onCreateView method.

The only work around to this that I could think of was declaring the priceView variable at the top of the class, defining it in the onCreateView method and then setting its text value elsewhere in the code.  That's not a solution because I don't know where I would set the text value so that it happens every time onCreate is called, or in real time.

I'd like to know if there is a workaround to this problem

PS: The database gets it's values in another activity through an http request to a website.

Comment: There are a number of ways to handle this. Where is getPriceOfCoins() located? Is it in your Fragment?

Comment: No, it's not.  It's in the activity's class

Comment: You can cast your get activity to the main activity and then call your method from it. ((MainActicity) get Activity()).getPriceOfCoins(); mixed with the below answer

Answer (score 1):

you could make the method static, adding a context as parameter:

```
public static  double getPriceOfCoins(Context contex, String coinType) {
       UserData userData = new UserData(context);
}
```

and invoke it like `NameOfActivity.getPriceOfCoins`, or if the activity that hosts the Fragment is the same that has the method you can cast the return value of getActivity() to your Activity, and call the method on the casted value

Comment: Sorry. should clarify.  That part isn't in the fragment.  I made a mistake.  It's in the regular activity.

Comment: @user126553 it is a public static so it doesn't need to be in the same class. You can call it statically